# AWS Dynamo-data-types AttributeValue.wrap() converts to SS (StringSet) rather than String[]

Tags: amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-dynamodb

The AWS DynamoDB AttributeValue.wrap() function is converting my string array to a SS (String Set).  Here is the code...

```
 var temp = {
    code:"A",
    guids: [
      "07088ea1-cb53-4bd3-b7a7-2a1fdf1e99ca",
      "30dce880-0b00-4682-b612-4b54dbf7caef",
    ]
   }
  
    var newRecord = dbDataTypes.AttributeValue.wrap(temp);
```

returns the guides as a String Set (SS)

```
   guids: {
    SS: [
      '07088ea1-cb53-4bd3-b7a7-2a1fdf1e99ca',
      '30dce880-0b00-4682-b612-4b54dbf7caef'
    ]
```

but i need it to return as per app sync...

```
   Guids": {
    "L": [
     {
      "S": "1dc8a478-d2af-4d84-ba57-4b1be4fb3c7c"
     },
     {
      "S": "dbe47150-1940-44cf-a264-421e63f0aacd"
     }
    ]
```

So that all my code can parse it in a consistent manner.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly state the data type that you want:

```
const opts = { types: { alphabets: 'L' } };

dbDataTypes.AttributeValue.wrap(guids,opts)
```

Based on your update you should wrap it inside the params:

```
const opts = { types: { alphabets: 'L' } };

var gu = [
      "07088ea1-cb53-4bd3-b7a7-2a1fdf1e99ca",
      "30dce880-0b00-4682-b612-4b54dbf7caef"
    ]


var temp = {
    code:"A",
    guids: dbDataTypes.AttributeValue.wrap(gu,opts)
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didnt work.  The input data in my question is only one level deep. While it works for the first level, it doesnt for its children.  ill update the question.
Can you send a link to the doco on this .wrap() please.

Comment: Updated my answer based on your input.

Comment: Thanks.  This is just a trivial example of my data.  I need the whole payload in DynamoDB Json format.   I will have to traverse the json data, which is what i was trying to avoid.

Comment: If you're simply trying to convert JSON to DynamoDB JSON then you have 2 better options than the current third party library your using... 1. Use marshall/unmarshall functions from the native SDK. 2. Use a Document Client which abstracts DynamoDB JSON